# Get Current customer billing information

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-address, customer-session

How to display login customer billing information on home page without load model `Mage::getModel'(customer/address')->load($addressId)`?

Comment: really you asked question, strange!...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it my self

```
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
if($customer && $customer->getId()) {
    $defaultBillingAddress = $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress();
    print_r($defaultBillingAddress);
}
```